# How to implement generic durandal refresh button?

Tags: durandal, sammy.js

How would I implement a refresh button in durandal? Is there something like this that works in  a generic way? I would like to implement this on many pages.

```
return router.navigateTo(router.activeRoute());
```

Or do I have to reconstruct the url from the viewmodel?

Comment: What would be the scope for the refresh? e.g. `window.location.reload()` for full page refresh. Might be a little to broad though.

Comment: Although my original thoughts were that the scope was the durandal view model, in fact for what I need your solution is quite good. This way the refresh button can be "global" to the app and resides in the shell.html "master page".

Comment: Please answer your own question with the bits you decided to implement. That will allow you to mark it as answer after a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RainerAtSpirit's answer to implement a refresh button on the shell view. The code fragment is show here:

```
mainRefresh = function () {
            window.location.reload();
        },
```

I think I have an underlying issue in my app about sometimes the data not loading but I will save that for another question.